# 'undefined reference' when using a function - Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I cannot build my project because I keep getting `undefined reference to *` errors.

I call my function from this:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_app_test_Renderer_00024Native_CreatePrimaryElements(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls) {
    GUI::LoadResources();
}
```

I define LoadResources function in gui.hpp

```
namespace GUI {
    LoadResources();
}
```

and implement it in gui.cpp

```
GUI::LoadResources() {...}
```

But when I try to build my project I keep getting `In function 'Java_app_test_Renderer_00024Native_CreatePrimaryElements' undefined reference to 'GUI::LoadResources()'` error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Stupid question-  are you including gui.hpp in whatever file you're putting the JNIEXPORT function?  And in the linker step are you linking in gui.cpp?

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes. I've synced the project several times to be sure gui.cpp is linked. I don't see any 'this file doesn't belong to any project' warnings when editing gui.cpp.